# Drag draggables into each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, draggable

My question is, if there is a way to drag jQuery's into each other? I know this is very vague so I'll show you what I mean.

I duplicated [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/MZLvN/) (so I can edit it) and applied some styling to it.

This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chrisstar56/8uwz4r90/).

You can see you can drag the "drag" elements into the first box. Now I need a solution if you drag one element on top of another, the item should be put into the other element. I hope you can help me, I never worked with that before. (I am not bound to using jQuery UI).

```
$(".container").droppable({
  // accept draggables only from #toolbox,
  // this will prevent cloning of the draggables(inside drop event handler),
  //  that already have been dropped inside #container
  accept: "#contain .drag",
  drop: function (event, ui) {
    // when a draggable is dropped: 
    // 1: clone it's helper 
    // 2: Make the helper draggable
    // 3: set containment to #container
    $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone().draggable({
      containment: "parent"
    }));
  }
});
$("#contain .drag").draggable({
  revert: "invalid",
  helper: "clone"
});
```

EDIT: Added a new fiddle, with a better markup.
P.S.:Thank you for the edit @Scott

Comment: What's with "#Some code because of jsfiddle link"?

Comment: Not certain I understand. *Both* your fiddle links appear to allow draggables to "stack" on top one another.

Comment: I want them to stack up like in the second box of the second example, not overlaying each other.

Comment: So if you drop a "drag" into the first box (second link), you want them to snap into a grid? Well, a grid that flows down then right, so "stacking"?

Comment: I am not a native speaker, so I must have confused a few words. I want to make them snap to the ones that already have been dropped there.

Comment: Oh, you **don't** want them to "stack up" you want then to **align** vertically. Okay...

Comment: I edited your question fro clarity Chrisstar. If you feel my edits are incorrect or unwarranted, please correct them. Thanks!

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen SO won't allow just a link to a fiddle without also including code in the question.. those were a way of circumventing that restriction.

Comment: @Scott: I know, and therefore it would be a good idea to actually include the code instead of circumventing site policy...

Comment: I don't disagree with that :)

Comment: I am quite new to stackoverflow, so I don't exactly know how this stuff works, and I didn't wanted that huge code block in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the state of the elements after they were dropped, then used jQuery to make them match the state of the elements in the second box.

First, I added the `style` class, then removed the `draggable` class. But since jQuery also used absolute positioning, I had to remove that from the element as well.

Be careful: the elements are `display: block`, so they won't stack left-to-right.

https://jsfiddle.net/p1fwf4L7/3/

Comment: That's a base, but sadly not what I need. I want the draggables to still beeing able to move and making the other draggables only align if you drop them just under the other ones.